# How to sort the list of buffers

Tags: buffers, autocompletion, filenames

How to sort the list of buffers Vim displays on entering `:b <Tab>` by most recent?

I'm used to the Spacemacs ordering, which displays buffer filenames in separate rows (vertically) in the order of most recent access.

I like accessing files by autocompleting the filename, so `:ls` is not an option. I do not interact with buffers in other ways, so I'm fine with breaking things or using plugins. I already use fzf.vim.

There were [some](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/how-to-go-to-previous-open-buffer-from-vim-command-line) [similar](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22160/is-there-a-way-to-list-recent-buffer-history) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184527/how-to-change-order-for-bnext-and-bprevious-in-vim), but nothing directly relevant to my problem.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "after :b" and "displaying vertically?"

Comment: Sorry, it is actually after `:b <Tab>`.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I have two recommendations for your cases: `bufexplorer` for viewing buffers; They are ordered by last used by default. Then `ctrl-p` for a fuzzy file finder. Super easy to use and even more useful.

Comment: Pretty sure tab completion of buffers is core, non-configurable functionality, i.e. short of someone basically (re)implementing something similar in vimscript you're stuck with lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Actually, looking at the accepted answer found through the third link you provided, which pretty much says what I said about tab completion ordering...you're not going to get any substantially different answer here. At least not without expanding your horizons beyond just tab completion. (FYI, the author was a major contributor here, too, and knows what they're talking about.)

Comment: Yeah, but something might have changed since 2011. I found something good enough: fzf.vim default settings bind `<Leader> b` to a list of buffers ordered by most recent, and tab-completion works. Could I bind `:b` to that?

Comment: A Normal mode mapping? Yes, but there will be some delay (configurable) when you want to go to the command line with `:`. Or do you mean map just `b` from command-line context? You can do that but I think you'll want to map it a particular way so you don't pick up any old `b` on the command line.

Comment: This (both my answer and some of the comments) have enough information to create the kind of command-line mapping I'm referring to. There's a lot of noise so what you'll be primarily interested in is the `cnoremap` in the second update.   [How to jump to buffer from ls?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14536)